# Requisição ajax não chega no servidor quando o body é muito grande

Tags: javascript, ajax, servidor, vue.js, axios

Em uma chamada ajax que faço para o servidor numa função de geração de relatório estou encontrando uma situação.

Quando no body da requisição eu mando um array pequeno, com 20 posições tudo acontece normalmente, porém quando eu mando uma requisição mais pesada, com cerca de 7400 posições no array a requisição nem chega ao servidor.

Estou usando a biblioteca [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) e estou fazendo o front-end em VueJS

A minha dúvida é:

Quando é efetuada uma requisição pesada, o Chrome ou qualquer outro navegador bloqueia ou a biblioteca bloqueia??

Comment: Você está recebendo alguma mensagem como `Error: Request body larger than maxBodyLength limit`?

Comment: qual linguagem back-end esta utilizando?

Comment: @Dobrychtop, não, não estou tendo nenhum erro, apenas retorna a response como undefined após algum tempo, porém tenho um `console.log` na função no servidor e quando a requisição é pequena, a função é executada, quando é maior não executa...

Comment: @JulioHenrique estou usando NodeJS com HapiJS

Comment: sabe me dizer qual servidor esta usando pra web? isso me parece configuração

Comment: Como assim servidor para web?? Você se refere a Nginx ou Apache??

Comment: exatamente, esta usando Apache?

Comment: Esta situação está ocorrendo localmente na minha máquina, não uso Apache ou nginx, em ambiente de desenvolvimento o VueJS não precisa de um servidor servindo ele,e em produção o servidor é Node, não é usado nem Apache nem nenhum outro

Comment: cara quando voce utiliza AJAX ele faz uma requisição http para algum servidor.. geralmente existe um limite de dados definido para nao crashar o servidor. na sua pergunta vc diz "servidor" seja qual estiver usando é nele que vc deve configurar

Comment: Entendi, vou dar uma olhada mais a fundo nas configurações do servidor, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: @LeonardoEbert o limite padrão para o `maxBodyLength` do axios é 10 MB, porém se fosse esse o problema você deveria estar recebendo a mensagem de erro que escrevi acima.

Comment: Pois é, isso é o mais estranho, não me retorna nenhum erro...